# Overview understanding of space, function, and transformation by an idea of plasticine. Need some comments for correction.

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, education, transformation

I would like give a overview idea of Space, Function, and Transformation by using plasticine as an idea.

About elementary geometry mathematic, it could be said that the basic things are basic shapes such as sphere, cube, pyramid, etc.
A collection of these shapes forms something that can hold any kind of shapes which is called “Space”. And we build up those shapes from the Space through some means. Like the plasticine, it just like a space.

When we want some shapes from the plasticine, we might not want to use hole of it, we might want to use some part, cut them out and make them into some shapes. To do that we need some thing that called “Function”, like we take some part of space to make some lines or more complex structure.

However for some shapes it is more convenient to mold the plasticine into some forms first before we cut them out and make a shape. Or we change the color of the plasticine by some how. You change the whole space into a new form but you did not change the characteristics of becoming a shape, that is “Transformation”.

Are these kind of comparisons are wrong?

Comment: It is all very vague and does not appear to contain a question.